# Upgrade sklearn model from 0.23.1 to >1.0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

so I have a random forest model saved as. a `.pkl` file. This model was trained using an older version of `sklearn` 0.21.3, I would like to use it within an environment that has to use a `sklearn` version that is greater than 1.0.0.

From 0.23.1 to 1.0.0 `sklearn` has changed the naming of modules,classes and function from `forest` to `_forest` as an example.
For that reason I currently cannot import the old model, as it will not be recognized as a `sklearn` model. I would be interested if there is away to convert such model file to a file that is importable under 1.0.0 or greater.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as always ones posted Stackoverflow, you will find the solution here:
https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/issues/82#issuecomment-1582995672

You can import the old model like so

```py
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import sklearn.tree
import sklearn.ensemble
import sklearn.neighbors
import sys
import numpy as np

#%%
sys.modules["sklearn.tree.tree"] = sklearn.tree
sys.modules["sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting"] = sklearn.ensemble
sys.modules["sklearn.ensemble.forest"] = sklearn.ensemble
sys.modules["sklearn.neighbors.classification"] = sklearn.neighbors

#%% load the old model
rf = pickle.load(open("../models/old_model.pkl", "rb"))

#%% save it as a new model
with open("../models/new_modle.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(rf, f)
```

There is no guarantee that the model works identical but for me it did.